# Watin and cursor on new IE

Tags: watin

I have a simple project like this :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var browser = new IE("http://toto.com", true);

        browser.TextField(Find.ById("f1")).SetAttributeValue("value", "my name");
        browser.TextField(Find.ById("f2")).SetAttributeValue("value", "my info");

        browser.Link(Find.ById("btn")).Click();     
    }
```

When I click on my button, the window's cursor go in the corner of the screen.
Do you know why ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the default behavior for watin. You can turn in off with the following:

Settings.AutoMoveMousePointerToTopLeft = false;